# Construct JSON from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this panda data frame containg info about id, description, field name, field value and email

```
                    id                    desc   field_name       val               eml  
0                    1            desc in id 1      field_1       300    test@gmail.com  
1                    1            desc in id 1      field_2       305    test@gmail.com  
2                    2            desc in id 2      field_3       530    test2@gmail.com   
3                    2            desc in id 2      field_4       745    test2@gmail.com   
3                    2            desc in id 2      field_1       845    test2@gmail.com
```

Here desc and email will be same for a particular id
So I want to construct an array of JSON by clubbing the id, desc and email

And all the changes on field name and val will be send by list of list format

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        desc: "desc in id 1",
        eml: "test@gmail.com"
        values: [ [field_1, 300], [field_2, 305]  ]
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        desc: "desc in id 2",
        eml: "test2@gmail.com"
        values: [ [field_3, 530], [field_4, 745], [field_1, 845]  ]
    }, 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

(If you google "pandas to json" the first hit is the link below ...)

You can use the [`pd.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) i.e

```py
df_json = df.to_json()
```

where the argument `orient` defines different outputs. You'll most likely use `orient="records"` to get it as a json-array e.g

```py
import pandas as pd
df_so = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3],"email":["foo@example.com","bar@example.com","baz@example.com"]})
print(df_so)
#   id  email
# 0 1   foo@example.com
# 1 2   bar@example.com
# 2 3   baz@example.com

df_so.to_json(orient="records")

#
#[{"id":1,"email":"foo@example.com"},
#{"id":2,"email":"bar@example.com"},
#{"id":3,"email":"baz@example.com"}]'
```

regarding your `values` you'll need to create that column first.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, But to_json() will not generate the json in desired format that I mentioned

Comment: have you set `orient="records"` as mentioned?